# Spark: Is window functions an alternative to custom partitioners?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm kind of really confused on how custom partitioners(RDD) are really applied in the latest spark versions (on Dataframes/Datasets).
Can all custom partitioners be handled through the SparkSQL's Window functions?
Or do we need to go back and forth between rdd and dataframes/datasets while custom partitioning?

Mainly, this is to partition data with complex keys and sort within it.

```
class CustomePartitioner(partitions: Int) extends Partitioner {
    override def numPartitions: Int = partitions
    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
      val k = key.asInstanceOf[tmpCaseClass]
      k.tmpCaseClass.SomeId.hashCode() % numPartitions
    }
  }

case clase tmpCaseClass {
    ....
  }

  object tmpCaseClass {
    implicit def orderingById[A <: tmpCaseClass] : Ordering[A] = {
       Ordering.by(fk => (fk.SomeId, fk.SomeName))
    }
  }
```

I don't have any concrete example on this as I'm not clear.
Can someone please explain with an example or point to an already answered topic that exactly explains this?